# How to draw a great circle of a sphere？

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I am the distance on the sphere? I wonder how to draw a section of a sphere with Sktechpad or other tools?

Since the sphere is shown on the plane, how to draw the great circle?

Comment: When you project the sphere down into the plane, you are applying a linear transformation. Merely apply the same transformation to the great circle.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be the circle representing the sphere in your drawing.
The images of great circles are ellipses whose center of symmetry coincides with the midpoint of $C$, and which touch $C$ in two points.